# BuddyPress xprofile repeater field

Tags: php, wordpress, field, repeat, buddypress

I've searched high and low for a plugin to extend BuddyPress xprofile fields to include the ability for the user to have repeating fields. I've yet to find a way to connect ACF repeating fields into xprofile fields, so I think building it myself may be the best route. Does anyone have any direction or suggestions as to how I should go about adding this functionality?

Comment: I'd like to know best practice for this also